# How to stop qtDesigner from resizing when adding widget to a layout?

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyqt5, qt-designer

Im having a problem:
as soon as I add some widgets to a layout they automatically resize and I cant change their size anymore...
In this case its the left list widget.[image]

Is there a way to stop them from resizing or else?

Thanks!

Edit: I want to add the Widgets to the centralwidget, so they resize if the main window gets resized.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding your problem. Can you explain the full procedure?

Comment: @musicamante sure, as soon as I add the list widget to a layout it resizes to the standard size. 
I only need the layout for letting the main window be resizeable.

The list widget one the right has the same size as the one on the left was.
I only added it into a layout with the label above and it resized

Comment: I believe you're misunderstanding the concept behind layout managers: they *manage* the layout, meaning that it's *their* responsibility to set the geometry of their widgets. As soon as a widget is added to a layout, you'll loose the possibility of resizing it with handles, as the layout will resize it whenever it finds it necessary. Also, if you need to ensure that widgets resize whenever their parent (or window) is resized, you must set the layout for that parent/window. Adding layouts is to create *nested* layouts only. See [using layouts in Designer](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-layouts.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use multiple Layouts to create a big one.

Dont forget spacers!